# How to create a sub-menu in the Windows shell context menu in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-shell

I am using `pInvoke`, `IShellExtInit` and `IContextMenu` to add a context menu to the explorer shell in C#.

I can add a single item to the context menu using the following code:

```
MENUITEMINFO mii = new MENUITEMINFO();
mii.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(mii);
mii.fMask = MIIM.MIIM_BITMAP | MIIM.MIIM_STRING | MIIM.MIIM_FTYPE | MIIM.MIIM_ID | MIIM.MIIM_STATE ;
mii.wID = idCmdFirst + increment;
mii.fType = MFT.MFT_STRING;
mii.dwTypeData = contextMenuItem.ItemText;
mii.fState = MFS.MFS_ENABLED;
mii.hbmpItem = this._pMenuBitmap;

NativeMethods.InsertMenuItem(hMenu, increment, true, ref mii)
```

What I'd like to do is add a menu tree; i.e. add a submenu to the newly created menu item. My first instinct was to use:

```
var subMenu = mii.hSubMenu;
...
NativeMethods.InsertMenuItem(subMenu,....)
```

But submenu is always a zero value.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It's not recommended to write shell extensions using managed code: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/18/1317290.aspx

Comment: @StephenEllis Did you ever implement this solution, I've gotten my context menu to display but now i'm trying to figure out how to handle clicks.  The invoke command method isn't called for the submenu.

Comment: @blak3r I did indeed. I'll have to have a look at the code again as I don't remember encountering a problem with the click-callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you mean you want to have a cascading submenu that pops out ?

You need to use:

- `CreatePopupMenu()` to create a new menu
- add/insert your menu items into it
- then use a `MENUITEMINFO` where you set the `.hSubMenu` to the handle of your menu, and use the `MIIM_SUBMENU | MIIM_TYPE` mask, to insert into the context menu you get via `IContextMenu:QueryContextMenu`.

http://forum.cockos.com/archive/index.php/t-20799.html